# Wishlist block prestashop

Tags: module, prestashop, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules

Is there a version of **wishlist** bock compatible with **PrestaShop 1.7.5.2**? Thanks

I tried to download from Market Place, but it was not possible. It seems that the version 1.7.5.2 is not supported. In the menu for compatible version, there is only 1.7.6

Comment: There's not. You can search for paid modules.